# What determines the "range" of a magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I've noticed that some magnets seemed to have a larger range of effect even though the actual strength of the magnets seem to be similar.

i.e. If I float one magnet on a container of water and hold a magnet up  to the side of the container there are different distances that different magnets have an observable effect on the floating magnet even though the magnets all appear to be equal strength.

In some cases weaker magnets seem to have a bigger range then stronger magnets.

Is this observational bias/error on my part or is there a factor that determines range separate from actual strength?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What you are claiming is contradictory and not backed up by measurements. On the one hand you are saying that all of the magnets "appear" to have the same strength - but you do not say how you determined this. On the other hand you are saying that the test which you used showed differences in strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "strength" of a magnet is called its "magnetic momentum" $\bf M$.

Provided that you are not very close to the magnet, the decrease of the field amplitude with the distance from the magnet scales as 
$$
B\propto |{\bf M}| / R^3
$$
and the proportionality coefficient only depends on the nature of the medium (on its "magnetic permeability", to be accurate).

So the "range" of the magnet really depends only on its "strength". If you measure a stronger or weaker field for two different magnets at the same distance, it simply means that their "strength" is actually not the same.